# Cannot upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.04

I do not have the option to upgrade to ubuntu 11.10 in my update manager window. So far I have changed the source from the United Kingdom server to the main server and have the normal releases option selected.

I haven't seen many other answers to this problem. Can someone please give me some advice?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against doing a web-based upgrade.

I'm sure you'd be better off [downloading the latest version and carrying out a clean install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

I've written [details on the Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 upgrade](http://technonstop.com/upgrade-ubuntu-11-04-to-11-10), along with the trouble faced.

Also, a [reader on the same site states in a comment](http://technonstop.com/gaming-ubuntu-linux#comment-562) on another article that he "never does a web upgrade" and suspected problems arising from that.

Comment: my upgrade crashed half way through a web upgrade, I managed to fix the install but it took the rest of the day. Now it ***sort of*** works

Answer (score 2):

Try using `update-manager -cd`. That will force it to check for an update.

Answer (score 0):

use this command may be help you

write sudo i

then type your password

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

apt-get dist-upgrade

and restart

if no change

try

to update from update manager like "Githlar" said because to update to lastest version you must be download and install all update so open it and press settings and put True mark in all tab for options and try to update now if no try to change server in every time

try this may be somthing Broken update or software

apt-get install -f